# Is there any Relationship between Eigenvectors and Characters?

Tags: abstract-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, characters

I noticed a strong similarity in the proofs of the linear independence of characters (homomorphisms from a given group $G$ to units of $\mathbb C$) and of eigenvectors with different eigenvalues).

However, I can't seem to find an obvious relationship between them (either a character as a kind of eigenvector or visa versa). I have found one relationship, but it feels unnatural. I understand that a character can be identified with a vector in $\mathbb C^{G}$, but I don't see an obvious way of defining an eigenvalue which is distinct for distinct characters. I do understand that if you define a matrix such that the entry corresponding to the elements of the group a and b is $f(ab^{-1})$ where $f$ is some character, then every character will be an eigenvector and if we consider linear combinations of such matrices, we should be able to find such a matrix, but this seems to rely on more complicated facts and may even be self referential.

Also, similar to the above is making a Cayley graph out of the group an using the adjacency matrix, but again, this feels unnatural unless I'm misunderstanding it.

Thanks for any advice you can give. I feel like there's something obvious that I'm missing.

Comment: Schur's lemma says that if $V$ is an irreducible representation of a group $G$ and $L:V\rightarrow V$ intertwines the representation then $L$ is multiplication by a scalar. That is it has a single eigenvalue.  You can realize every irreducible representation in $\mathbb{C}[G]$ viewed as an left module over itself, so if you can find an intertwiner of this space that has enough eigenvalues, it's eigenspaces will correspond to the irreducible representations of $G$.  In the case of a compact Lie group, the Laplace operator is just what you need.  Chances are there is an analog for a finite group

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense and well clarifies how to find an eigenvalue (although my background in representation theory is a bit weak). However, I was hoping for a more elementary relationship between characters and eigenvalues that clarified why the traditional proofs seem so similar.